Why did Resolve[] fail to verify a statement whose counter-example was proven to be nonexistant by FindInstance[]?
I wanted to know whether the following statement is correct.

Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be positive real numbers such that $abcd=1$, then
$$\frac{(3 a+1) (d-1)}{a+1}+\frac{(a-1) (3 d+1)}{d+1}+\frac{(3 b+1) (c-1)}{b+1}+\frac{(b-1) (3 c+1)}{c+1}\geq 0$$
always holds.

I tried to use FindInstance[] to find a counterexample,
FindInstance[{((a - 1) (3 d + 1))/(d + 1) + ((b - 1) (3 c + 1))/(
    c + 1) + ((c - 1) (3 b + 1))/(b + 1) + ((d - 1) (3 a + 1))/(
    a + 1) < 0, a b c d == 1}, {a, b, c, d}, PositiveReals]

The output came quickly and it was an empty list {}.
I then tried to use Resolve[] to verify it,
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c, 
   d}, {a b c d == 1}, ((a - 1) (3 d + 1))/(
    d + 1) + ((b - 1) (3 c + 1))/(c + 1) + ((c - 1) (3 b + 1))/(
    b + 1) + ((d - 1) (3 a + 1))/(a + 1) >= 0], PositiveReals]

But the evaluation lasted for a long time.
Why is it so?

The software failed to evaluate the second code. The kernel quit for some reason (perhaps out of memory)

Do not use more variables than necessary. If you eliminate one variable using "a b c d ==1", Resolve evaluates quickly to True:
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, 
   c}, ((a - 1) (3 d + 1))/(d + 1) + ((b - 1) (3 c + 1))/(c + 
        1) + ((c - 1) (3 b + 1))/(b + 1) + ((d - 1) (3 a + 1))/(a + 
        1) >= 0 /. d -> 1/(a b c)], PositiveReals]

True


One can work with four variables, considering the negation of the implication..
Resolve[Exists[{a, b, c, d},  a  b  c  d == 
1 && ((a - 1)  (3  d + 1))/(d + 1) + ((b - 1)  (3  c + 1))/(c + 
    1) + ((c - 1)  (3  b + 1))/(b + 
    1) + ((d - 1)  (3  a + 1))/(a + 1) < 0], PositiveReals]


False

Addition. In 14.1 on Windows 10
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c, d},  Implies[a b c d == 
1, ((a - 1) (3 d + 1))/(d + 1) + ((b - 1) (3 c + 1))/(c + 
    1) + ((c - 1) (3 b + 1))/(b + 1) + ((d - 1) (3 a + 1))/(a + 
    1) >= 0]], PositiveReals]


True

in few minutes.

See Wiki concerning the negation of the implication.

I'll try the code later. So Exists[] is more efficient than ForAll[]?

@youthdoo: More exactly, the negation of the quantified implication appears simpler  for Resolve than that implication.

In[1]:= Implies[a b c d ==                                                      
1, ((a - 1) (3 d + 1))/(d + 1) + ((b - 1) (3 c + 1))/(c +                       
    1) + ((c - 1) (3 b + 1))/(b + 1) + ((d - 1) (3 a + 1))/(a +                 
    1) >= 0]//BooleanConvert//InputForm                                         

Out[1]//InputForm= 
a*b*c*d != 1 || ((1 + 3*b)*(-1 + c))/(1 + b) + ((-1 + b)*(1 + 3*c))/(1 + c) + 
   ((1 + 3*a)*(-1 + d))/(1 + a) + ((-1 + a)*(1 + 3*d))/(1 + d) >= 0

Hence you no longer have an equation that can be used to eliminate a variable. One more variable in an algorithm that is doubly exponential in the number of variables makes a difference.
